# Store Multiple Emails in Array - Html Input Element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have a small form of React Bootstrap. My goal is I want to store multiple Emails that user enters in a input field and store them in an Array. But I see if I use

```
onChange={()=> setEmails(e.target.value as any}
```

it stores them in string like this --> xyz@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com
what I want is ['xyz@gmail.com',abc@gmail.com];

I'm using React Js and here's a little overview of my code

```
const [emails, setEmail] = useState<string[]>([])

 <Form.Control required onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} value={emails} style={{ borderRadius: '0' }}  multiple type="email" />
```

Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Here's the code that helped me achive my goal

```
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
```

In handle Change I split the values on comma (,) and it helped me seprating the emails ids. Catch here is In the input field I need to add a comma after every email id for example :- abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,example@ymail.com

```
  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    let email = e.target.value.split(",")
    setEmail(email)
}
```

Comment: It would still have single email

Comment: please make your question clear 1. Do you want to have a single field with comma separated emails or 2. you have dynamic rows of email inputs that you want to accumulate into a single array ?

Comment: Also add maximum possible repliactable code so it helps in understanding.

Comment: This My state 
`const [emails, setEmail] = useState<string[]>([])` 

and this my onChange method I'm applying on a form input field

`<Form.Control required onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} value={emails} style={{ borderRadius: '0' }} multiple type="email" />`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a new email everytime. What you would want is to **push** a new value to the previous State value.

Try this:

```
onChange={(e) => setEmail(prev => [...prev,e.target.value])}
```

`...` [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator expands the array elements.

Comment: whenever I try to type something it gives this error :- TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null